# How to create a custom seekbar for music player in actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating simple music player. It will play just one song. I want to create a very simple seekbar. I would like one graphic to work as seek component - so it can be moved to the right and left (between two points on x axis: starting point where the graphic is at the moment, and ending point where it will be when song ends) and correspond to channel.position of the song. So to wrap up: I want to ask a kind soul to give me a hint of what code should I use to make graphic move on axis x in a way that corresponds to channel.position of the song.

This is my code so far:

```
movieClip_1.stop(); 
var itsstoped:Boolean; 
var youpausedit:Boolean; 
var counter:Timer = new Timer(100); 
var chan:SoundChannel; 
var song:Sound = new Sound();
song.load(new URLRequest("wmc2.mp3")); 
song.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundloaded);
function soundloaded(event:Event)
{
trace("Song has been loaded.");
} 
counter.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,countcounter);  
itsstoped = true; 
youpausedit = false;  
button_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, presser);
function presser(event:MouseEvent):void
{
if(itsstoped == true && youpausedit == true)
{
    movieClip_1.gotoAndPlay(1);
    chan = song.play(chan.position);
    itsstoped = false; 
} 
else if(itsstoped == false)
{
    movieClip_1.gotoAndStop(1);
    chan.stop();
    itsstoped = true;
    youpausedit = true;
}   
else if(itsstoped == true && youpausedit == false)
{
    movieClip_1.gotoAndPlay(1);
    chan = song.play();
    counter.start();
    itsstoped = false; 
} 
}  
function countcounter(e:TimerEvent):void
{
trace(chan.position/song.length);
var percentage:uint = 100 * (chan.position / song.length);
trace(percentage);
if(percentage == 100)
{   movieClip_1.gotoAndStop(1);
    itsstoped = true;
    youpausedit = false;
    }
}
```

Ignore the movieClip_1 as it's just animation that runs when music plays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEFrame);

function onEFrame(e:Event):void
{
   graphic.x = graphicStartX + music.position/music.length*(graphicEndX-graphicStartX);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. I'll try that, but what about the code for user dragging and dropping action, should I change that graphic into a button?

Comment: I have tried your code and it works but gives me three of those in output window: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. Is that because my timeline is only one frame? Any other event i can "listen to" instead ENTER_FRAME, to not get this error? Also if you could relate to my previous question, I will apriciate this a lot. @SzRaPnEL

Answer (score 0):

Problem laid in this line of code:

```
var chan:SoundChannel;
```

I have changed it to:

```
var chan = new SoundChannel();
```

And Error #1009 is no longer showing.

Hurray! :)